# the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I'm trying to upload file using simple fileuploader but I keep getting this error:

```
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
            <param-value>40960</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>uploadDirectory</param-name>
            <param-value>/home/alen/uploads</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
            <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
            <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

XHTML:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width:100%;" class="imageUploadTable">
        <p:fileUpload value="#{objave.file}" mode="simple"/>

        <f:facet name="footer">

            <p:commandButton actionListener="#{objave.spremiSliku()}"
                             value="Spremi"
                             icon="ui-icon-disk"
                             ajax="false"/>
        </f:facet>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Objave.java

```
private UploadedFile file;

public String spremiSliku() {
    System.out.println(file.getFileName());
    return "";
}
```

If I use advanced fileUploader then everything is ok, but I need simple fileUploader, and can't get it to work. I'm PrimeFaces noob so I don't know how to fix this. Can some help me with this?

Comment: There could be some version incompatibilities between JSF and PrimeFaces. What versions of JSF and PrimeFaces do you happen to use? Do you not mistakenly nest forms in your real code, by the way?

Comment: @Tiny JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 5.0

Comment: @Tiny Yes, it was actually nested forms, I didn't see it. Sorry for stupid question but this is the first time I use PrimeFaces

Comment: It's not a PrimeFaces-related problem. Nested forms are invalid in HTML. You might want to spend a bit more time into learning basic HTML before diving into server side languages which produce HTML code.